# wxpython panel doesn't resize

Tags: wxpython, panel

I can't seem to solve this one by myself.

I have 3 widgets in my wxPython Frame. Two stacked horizontaly and one below them. Here is the code:

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, name="MyFrame"):

        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        boxV = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        boxH1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        boxH2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        combo = wx.ComboBox(panel1, -1, size=(200, -1), choices=['A', 'B', 'C'], style=wx.CB_READONLY, value="Izberite COM vrata")
        button = wx.Button(panel1, -1, size=(100, -1), label="Connect")

        boxH1.Add(combo, 1, wx.ALL, 10);
        boxH1.Add(button, 1, wx.ALL, 10)

        boxH2.Add(wx.TextCtrl(self, -1), 1, wx.EXPAND)

        boxV.Add(boxH1, 0)
        boxV.Add(boxH2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        panel1.SetSizer(boxH1);

        self.SetSizer(boxV);

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, title="Simulation")

        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

As I see it, this should work. And it does... sort of... if i manualy set the size of the panel it will expand and it will look ok. But it should expand automaticaly. i have made a screenshot to see what I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change these 3 lines:

```
    boxV.Add(boxH1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    boxV.Add(boxH2, 1, wx.EXPAND)

    panel1.SetSizerAndFit(boxH1);
```

SetSizerAndFit let the panel figure out dimensions by itself.